# Include extra dependency in pyproject.toml in addition to requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, packaging, setup.py, pyproject.toml

I have a pyproject.toml with:

```
[project]
name="my_package"
version="0.0.1"
dynamic = ["dependencies"]

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
dependencies = {file=["requirements.txt"]}
```

However the requirements file has a git repo in it:

```
-e git+https://github/my_user/SomePackage@3648somehash973496
```

The dependency read of the requirements doesnt like the git repo, but works OK when I remove it.

Is it possible to add the git repo to the dependencies after they are read from the requirements.txt file?

Comment: "*…doesnt like the git repo…*: What exactly does it mean? Any error message?